# Dynamically read and store values in variables in shell

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I am trying to do this...

```
echo "Enter the number of fruits\n"
read fruit

echo $inp # this will print the number of fruits to enter
```

if fruit is 4

the script should be able to dynamically ask the user to input [4] fruits and store it into 4 variable like below.

```
fruit1=apple
fruit2=jack fruit
fruit3=pineapple
fruit4=grapes
```

i tried the below, but that doesn't help

```
for i in `seq 1 $fruit`
                    do
                            echo "Enter fruit$i\n"
                            read fruit[$i]
                            echo "fruit[$i]"
                    done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your shebang `#!/bin/sh`? `#!/bin/ksh`? Something else?

Comment: BTW, this topic (indirect variable assignment to arrays) is covered in general in BashFAQ #6 (which, yes, covers shells other than bash); see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: ...and even if your shebang is `#!/bin/ksh`, how are you actually starting your script? If you start it with `sh yourscript`, then it's run with POSIX sh, not ksh, regardless of its shebang.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  sorry #!/bin/ksh

Comment: ...and if you put `echo "ksh version: $KSH_VERSION"` in your script, it emits what?

Comment: echo "ksh version: $KSH_VERSION"
ksh version:

Comment: BTW, `fruit1` `fruit2` `fruit3` `fruit4` is different from `fruit=( apple "jack fruit" pineapple grapes )`, which is what `fruit[$i]` is doing.

Comment: If the `KSH_VERSION` variable is empty, your shell isn't ksh, which explains why it isn't accepting valid ksh syntax.

Comment: what other way can i express my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97908/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ady6831983).

Comment: so how can i make my shell KSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grow the array dynamically at each step.  Assume you start with the count, initialize the empty array and add elements one by one.

```
count=4; fruits=(); 
for i in `seq "$count"`; 
       do read f; fruits+=( "$f" ); 
       done; 
echo "${fruits[@]}"
```

works in version: 
Version AJM 93t+ 2010-06-21.

This works with BASH in AIX

Comment: #!/bin/sh
count=4; fruits=();
for i in `seq "$count"`;
       do read f; fruits+=( "$f" );
       done;
echo "${fruits[@]}"


./ar.sh[2]: syntax error at line 2 : `(' unexpected

Comment: @ady6831983, you wouldn't get that error with ksh; that's a POSIX sh limitation.

Comment: @ady6831983, with which *precise* version of ksh?

Comment: (as another aside, using `seq` is a code smell; it's not part of POSIX sh or a POSIX-specified utility, and thus not guaranteed to exist at all).

Comment: @Karakfa  Anyway i can get this running on AIX?

Comment: I'm not sure about AIX.  Don't have access to one to test.

Comment: @karakfa can you explain 
       
     fruits+=( "$f" );

Comment: It's adding a new element to the array, where new element is the value read.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `ksh88`- and `pdksh`-compatible version:

```
count=4
set -A fruits
i=0
while (( i < count )); do
    echo "Enter fruit$i"
    read fruits[i]
    (( i += 1 ))
done
echo "${fruits[@]}"
```

Tested with `/bin/ksh` (ksh88) on Solaris 8, and `pdksh` on MirBSD (whose native `mksh` supports the `+=()` notation, but on which I have other shells installed for delta testing).